# Get the vtable address in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm willing to use `unsafe`. How can I get a class virtual table address and convert it to an int?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Take a look at `OpCodes.Callvirt` through a disassembler. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.callvirt.aspx

Comment: @Matthew Opcodes.Callvirt is just a byte sequence. You need to look at the CLR standard or Mono's source.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: Nothing yet. I am just brainstorming. I was thinking maybe I can get the pointer for the first member, maybe use attributes to ensure its at offset 0 and then read 4-8bytes before it. Then compare to other instances of the same type to see if its a 4 or 8 byte ptr (and if its correct). Then see if its the same for all similar classes. But maybe the boxing structure/class is documented which is nice. Also I was wondering if i can do something with marshling and not need unsafe. Its just brainstorming ATM.

Comment: I'm also thinking if its simple to get the address of a function I can check if what i think the vtable is has the addresses of 2 or so of my methods. But... I don't really care for that ATM I just want to play with discovering how to get the vtable address

Comment: I doubt `fixed` would be needed as it is stored in the executable and so would be at a constant (per compile) relative address to the virtual address load base.

Comment: Anyways, finding the JIT code for mono is becoming a pain. (I'm not a mono Dev)

Comment: I'm sure there is meta data and in ILAsm i can see if a class is abstract or not. I don't really want to examine the binary at runtime to figure it out. Actually that may not work because idk where the jit would put it in memory. So... Lets get back into doing something like a memcpy and getting the pointer to the first member or maybe I can do something with addresses of a static variable/method/constructor(!?!)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634660/how-are-vtables-implemented-in-c-and-c

Comment: What, exactly, makes you think there _is_ a vtable? Is there something about OO that demands that virtual methods be implemented through a vtable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(EDIT: Shoot - forgot you have to also make sure it's not inlined - see edit)

You don't need unsafe, but you do need to make sure the method has been JIT'ed (which `.PrepareMethod` does):

caveat: I'm not entirely certain (without some more research) how accurate these numbers are long term; I know that at one point they **used** to be accurate, as I once used this to runtime swap method implementations... *shh*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
void Main()
{
    long typeHandle = typeof(Foo).TypeHandle.Value.ToInt64();
    Console.WriteLine("addressOf(typeof(Foo)): 0x{0:x}", typeHandle);

    MethodInfo instanceMethod1 = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("InstanceFunc1");
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(instanceMethod1.MethodHandle);
    long addressOfInstanceMethod1 = instanceMethod1.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt64();
    Console.WriteLine("foo.InstanceFunc1:      0x{0:x}", addressOfInstanceMethod1);

    MethodInfo instanceMethod2 = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("InstanceFunc2");
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(instanceMethod2.MethodHandle);
    long addressOfInstanceMethod2 = instanceMethod2.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt64();
    Console.WriteLine("foo.InstanceFunc2:      0x{0:x}", addressOfInstanceMethod2);

    MethodInfo staticMethod = typeof(Foo).GetMethod("StaticFunc");
    RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(staticMethod.MethodHandle);
    long addressOfStaticMethod = staticMethod.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt64();
    Console.WriteLine("Foo.StaticFunc:         0x{0:x}", addressOfStaticMethod);
}

public class Foo
{
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
   public static int StaticFunc() { return 1; } 
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
   public int InstanceFunc1() { return 1; } 
   [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
   public int InstanceFunc2() { return 1; }
}
```

Comment: Why would it move functions around in memory? They are objects, so wouldn't they just stay at a constant address (that changes per compile)

Comment: @ColeJohnson Sorry, horribly misspoke and didn't proofread: I meant to say the layout of objects and other references have changed from version to version of the CLR; most notably between 2.0->4.0. I'll make an edit. Also, good edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this article - it's for .NET 1.1 but it's a start. Since JIT internals are not very well documented, I'm not sure how well this applies to current framework versions.

[How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)

[This SO question may also be useful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634621/where-could-i-get-the-information-about-the-in-memory-layout-info-of-net-object)