# Theoretically determine the memory occupied by an array of structs?

Tags: c#, memory

I have a 64 bit processor.How much memory will this occupy?

```
var x = new point[3]; 

public struct point
{
   int x;//4 bytes
   int y;//4 bytes
}
```

My guess would be that, the stack will hold a reference to the heap. Since I have a 64 bit processor, the reference itself would be 8 bytes.

On the heap three "points" would be initialized. So that would be atleast 24 (8x3) bytes.

Is there a way to theoretically determine the exact memory occupied by x?

Comment: @TGH huh? any link/reasoning about "Structs go on the stack" statement? - you clearly know more than described in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

Comment: See: Implementation detail.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can relatively easy figure out amount of memory used by an object - you are almost there.

Here is approximate list of pieces you need to count for a reference type like `Array`:

- reference to an heap location (size depends on x86/x64)
- generic header of an object on the heap - sync block + type handle (size depends on x86/x64)
- all fields of an object (size used for reference type fields depends on x86/x64)
- for each reference type count corresponding objects.
- for arrays count "number of elements * size of element (including possible alignment)"

So you rough computation missing header and fields (like "Length").

Details are covered in many source like:

- [How the CLR Creates Runtime Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163791.aspx)
- collection of links in [Where could I get the information about the in-memory layout info of .NET Object Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634621/where-could-i-get-the-information-about-the-in-memory-layout-info-of-net-object)

Comment: Of course, then you have to take into account the Sync block index and Type pointer, etc. What possible use there could be for knowing the exact size of these things in a managed environment though is another question..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof`.. since you're wondering how much memory is allocated (regardless of where it is allocated - implementation detail):

```
unsafe {
    var sizeRequired = sizeof(point) * 3;
}
```

If you want to include the size of the reference you can just add it on..